# How to remove google maps markers and replace with new ones? HTTP Request

Tags: java, android, json, google-maps

Ok, here's an explanation of my question. At first, I create many markers on my map from data that obtained from the server. Now, what I want to do is make a new request and get new markers, but remove all the markers created before. I cannot make

```
map.clear();
```

because I have a GroundOverlay on my map, and If I do that it disappears also.
Any idea how to do that? I will appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

You can store your markers in a `List` or any collection and then loop through them and remove them by calling the `remove()` function of the marker. Also, when you call map.addMarker(...) you get the `Marker` object back which you can add to your list of stored markers.

```
List<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();
markers.add(map.addMarker(...)); // for example
...
...
//Later
for(Marker marker: markers) {
   marker.remove();
}
```